# How to render view template using node js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, firebase-realtime-database

I create an Ajax request (below) which passes data to the server with the information I need.

```
function verify(key) {

    $.ajax({
      async: true,
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/zonepass/'+key,
      data: { 
        'zone_key': key
      },
      success: function(res){
          //alert('Sent a text message successfully to ' + res);
      }

    });
}
```

I handle the Ajax request on the server side where I use the passed in data to query my Firebase DB to get other relevant information.

I then try to render the view page that I want to navigate to using `res.render('verify',{zone: obj, key: zone_key})` where verify is another `.ejs` file that I want to navigate the user to and the JSON object is the data that I want to pass to that template.

My code is not rendering the view page and I'm not sure why. I console logged all the data on the server and all the data is being pulled properly but then my view page never navigates to the verify ejs file...

```
app.get('/zonepass/:id', function(req,res) {
  var zone_key = req.param('zone_key');
  var zone_obj = firebase.database().ref('zones').child(zone_key).once('value').then((snap) => {
    obj = snap.val();
    res.render('verify',{zone: obj, key: zone_key});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`res.render` will not work with an `ajax` request, response from ajax call is returned and accessible inside the `success` function, but `res.render` will not work also `res.redirect` will not work with `ajax` request.

So you need to submit your request using a form or redirecting on frontend to that route, which is technically also a `get` request but without `ajax` example:

Using only HTML:

```
<a href="/zonepass/<your id>?zone_key=<your zone key>">Verify</a>
```

Using javascript:

```
function verify(key) {
    window.location.href= "/zonepass/"+ <your id> + "?zone_key=<your zone key>"
}
```

Also in your NodeJS route you can access `id` using `req.params.id` and `zone_key` using `req.query.zone_key`, so your server code will be:

```
app.get('/zonepass/:id', function(req,res) {

    var id = req.params.id;          
    var zone_key = req.query.zone_key;
    var zone_obj = firebase.database().ref('zones').child(zone_key).once('value').then((snap) => {
           obj = snap.val();
           res.render('verify',{zone: obj, key: zone_key});
    });
});
```

BTW you will need to handle inside the verify view, if the key is not verified, example you show an error or message in verify view, that the key is not correct ... or any message related to your logic

Comment: I can't do a redirect using the above ways because I need to pass the zone object and the key object to the template as well

Comment: also my get request is trying to pull this: GET /zonepass/-KxRo2jOvG8lX9VhIWoq?zone_key=-KxRo2jOvG8lX9VhIWoq 500 15.504 ms - 865.

How do I prevent my request from adding the extra data (?zone_key=...) this is the object that I'm passing to my server but its getting added to the GET url request

Comment: Yes this will pass them to the template, what the above is doing is the same as your request it will end inside your route, its the same `get` request but without using `ajax` ... i edited the code to consider `zone_key` as query parameter as well, so now you are still sending both `id` and `zone_key`

Comment: 1. how do I pull out the id from the url if I do it the javascript way? On the server side, I need to pull out the url to send it to the template



2. I will eventually have to mask my url for production/security purposes so would this method still work because it would become difficult for me to pull out the id from the url on the server side..?

Comment: The point is that the javascript way or the html way are both considered a `get` request so when you do `document.href.location = "/zonepass/"+ <your id> + "?zone_key=<your zone key>"` the server route will have the same request you did using `ajax`  ...  i also mentioned in the answer how you pull the `id` and `zone_key` from the request using `req.params.id` and `req.query.zone_key`  ... the most important point is to understand that the above way is a normal `get` request and for the server its the same as your ajax request