# Implementing search in js

Tags: javascript, express

I've been trying to implement some searching features. I need the program to read search area and redirect the user to the page with results. Here's my `search.ejs`

```
   <script>
            function executeSearch($this) {
                    console.log('button clicked');
                    let request_data = document.getElementById('search-area').value;
                    console.log("Request data : " + request_data);
                    $.post("search", {subtitle: request_data}, function(json) {
                console.log('requested access completed');   
            })
            }
    </script>
            <input id="search-area" type="search" value="" placeholder="Enter movie title" />
            <button onclick="executeSearch(this)" class="details-button">Search</button>


            <ul class="search-list">
                    <% for(let i=0; i< movieList.length; i++) { %>
                            <li class="single-search-result">
                                    <h3 class="text-light">
                                            <%=movieList[i].title%>
                                    </h3>
                                    <br>
                            </li>
                            <% } %>
            </ul>
```

Here's the code handling the request :

```
app.post('/search', (req, res) => {
movie_controller.getBySubTitle(req.body.subtitle)
    .then(result => {
        res.render('search', {
            movieList: result
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.render(500);
    })});
```

By using console.log, I've determined that there are no issues in transferring required data, however I can't render 'search' page after getting data from getBySubtitle(). Any ideas what can be causing this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Console result to confirm that is data is empty.and you can debug node js code in chrome browser using node --inspect server.js

Comment: You can't use `res.render` with ajax call as the response of ajax call is returned and accessible inside the request callback only, so you will need to consider using a normal get request using html or javascript without ajax .... check this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969763/how-to-render-view-template-using-node-js-express/46970159#46970159